# Genuine or not Genuine - Windows 7 is confused

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I have a fully-licensed, genuine Win7 installation that I recently had to overlay a new OS on, after some issues. I reinstalled over the top of the existing OS to retain as much of the existing data as possible. This was successful in almost all respects.
Ordinarily I would have restored the last backup, but part of the issue was it was corrupted. [Turned out to be a faulty SATA cable so all fixed now, but that backup remains unusable.]
There have been no hardware changes.

However, I now have the situation where getting Properties on My Computer shows it is correctly activated & recognised as genuine - yet several times a day I get the "This computer is not running genuine Windows" pop-up.

The link provided in the 'Resolve online now' notification is no longer valid, so I can't just click through to resolve this as I would have in the past.

Clicking through the 'learn more online' leads me to resolutions where the activation is not considered yet completed.

Other than ringing Microsoft, which I don't want to do, is there any way to resolve this dilemma?
Is there a current link I can click through to which will validate the installation, or is there some registry entry which needs correcting?

[image]

Nuke & pave is not an option; I have authorisations on this legacy machine for which the authorising servers no longer exist.

Comment: run [Microsoft Genuine Diagnostics Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012) and insert the text output here.

Comment: If you only need windows to be genuine so you can use the other licenced software you have on it, there are *alternative* methods if all else fails.

Answer (score 2):

You could try re-installing the key using the command prompt:

1. Open Start Menu and type `cmd`
2. The Start Menu will list cmd as an application. Right-click it and select "Run As Administrator".
3. In the command prompt execute `slmgr.vbs -ipk <your licence key>`
4. To activate windows execute `slmgr.vbs -ato`